# Secure networking - ServerSocket vs SSLServerSocketFactory?

Tags: java, ssl, networking

My school A Level project involves networking and it is a small client chat application that will use RSA encryption.

When looking into security, I found the SSLServerSocketFactory class and I have been reading lots of forums and threads but decided to create my own post.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/UseSSLServerSocketFactorytocreateaSSLServer.htm
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLServerSocketFactory.html

What I do not understand - why is using a ServerSocket bad practice in the industry? And what does an SSLServerSocketFactory actually do that makes it safer than the former ServerSocket?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It isn't 'bad practice in the industry'. It is used whenever you want to accept plaintext sockets. `SSLServerSocket` and friends are used when you want to accept TLS/SSL connections. And TLS/SSL is more secure than plaintext.

Comment: I see, okay. Thank you.